# How do I define a scaffold template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each time I generate a scaffold I need to customize the stylesheet. So it takes much more time to update style for index, form and show page. If I paste the predefined template code then I will have to change rails code instance variables and path.

Is there any way to define a specific style for each and every scaffold so that I used this to save time and overhead.

In short, I want to layout my page generate from scaffold like my form, index and show page with a predefined style.

I want to use custom mark-up and stylesheet in the generated scaffold. I want to do a one time definition of this scaffold template and use it every time I generate a new scaffold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved my problem though .

rails g bootstrap:layout [LAYOUT_NAME]

and

rails g bootstrap:themed [RESOURCE_NAME]

generate a scaffold by this command
rails g scaffold product name:string description:text

then implement bootstrap theme on your scaffold through this command

rails g bootstrap:themed products -f

pass the -f option to force it to overwrite the generated view files

you can generate a layout through command.

rails g bootstrap:layout appstructure
this file will be save in view/layout and reflect on each and every page.